# how to copy local file to azure vm through terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform

I am trying to create a VM in Azure using terraform and copy a file from local machine to the remote virtual machine on azure.

```
    os_profile {
    computer_name = "pdemo"
    admin_username = "ubuntu"
  }
  os_profile_linux_config {
    disable_password_authentication = true
    ssh_keys {
      key_data = "ssh-rsa ********************************** "
      path = "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys"
    }
  }
  provisioner "file" {
    connection {
      type = "ssh"
      user = "ubuntu"
      host = azurerm_public_ip.terraform-PUBLIC-IP.ip_address
      private_key = file("/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa")
    }
    source = "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/terraform.pub"
    destination = "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/terraform.pub"
  }
}
```

It gives an error:

```
azurerm_virtual_machine.terraform-app-VM: Still creating... [1m30s elapsed]
azurerm_virtual_machine.terraform-app-VM: Still creating... [1m40s elapsed]
azurerm_virtual_machine.terraform-app-VM: Still creating... [6m20s elapsed]
azurerm_virtual_machine.terraform-app-VM: Still creating... [6m30s elapsed]

Error: timeout - last error: SSH authentication failed (ubuntu@:22): ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check the private key that you are using as the error shows authentication issues.

Also add `agent=false` like this:

```
provisioner "file" {
    connection {
      type = "ssh"
      user = "ubuntu"
      host = azurerm_public_ip.terraform-PUBLIC-IP.ip_address
      private_key = file("/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa")
      agent    = false
      timeout  = "10m"
    }
    source = "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/terraform.pub"
    destination = "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/terraform.pub"
  }
```

Comment: The private key is correct because the virtual machine is running and I can ssh to it using the private key.

Comment: Did you try with `agent=false`

Comment: Yes, but still the same issue.

Comment: Try changing the permission of private key to 600. `chmod 600 /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa`

Comment: I have noticed that if you run the terraform script for the first time it gives an error:
Error: timeout - last error: SSH authentication failed (ubuntu@:22): ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain

And if I run the code again for the second time it gives an error:
Error: timeout - last error: dial tcp 40.114.2.59:22: i/o timeout

And if I run the code for the third time it works.
DO you know what is the problem?

Comment: That's strange. Unfortunately I have never experienced this.